# Accessing child scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using ngTagsInput angular. My problem comes from trying to gain access to displayTags from a parent root scope. It's not there. I want to gain access to it because the user can add new tags to displayTags which is working perfectly. I want to take those new tags and post them. How do I gain access to displayTags in a $root outside of the loops?

Angular code like so :

```
var app = angular.module('recGroups', ['ngTagsInput']);

app.directive('group', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: '../../Content/templates/RecruitingGroups/Group.html',
        link: function (scope, el) {
            //RemoveGroup
            scope.removeGroup = function (groupArray, index) {
                groupArray.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    }
});

app.directive('rule', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: '../../Content/templates/RecruitingGroups/Rule.html',
        link: function (scope, el) {
            scope.removeRule = function (ruleArray, index) {
                ruleArray.splice(index, 1);
            }

            scope.addTag = function () {
                scope.$parent.rule.Rules.push({});
            }
        }
    }
});

app.directive('tag', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: '../../Content/templates/RecruitingGroups/Tag.html',
        controller: 'displayTags',
        link: function (scope, el) {
            scope.removeTag = function (tagArray, index) {
                tagArray.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    }
});

app.controller('displayTags', function ($scope, data) {
    $scope.displayTags = [];
    // tag stuff to manipulate when have proper tag model
    if ($scope.tag.TagIds != null) {
        $.each($scope.tag.TagIds, function (scopeIndex, scopeValue) {
            $.each(data.Project.Tags, function (tagIndex, tagValue) {
                if (tagValue.Id == scopeValue) {
                    $scope.displayTags.push({ Id: tagValue.Id, Name: tagValue.Name, ProjectId: tagValue.ProjectId });
                }
            });

        });
    }

});
```

I am also submitting this image as a visual display of the html:
[image]

The Html is simplified is like so:

```
  <group ng-repeat="group in groups">
       <rule ng-repeat="rule in group.Rule.Rules">
          <tag ng-repeat="tag in rule.Rules">
            <tags-input ng-model="displayTags" display-property="Name">
            </tags-input>
          </tag>
       </rule>
    </group>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `scope: true`, you could use a [bi-directional binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#-scope-) like my exemple below.

```
scope: {
    displayTags: '=' // Bi-directional binding
}
```

Or if `displayTags` is your `model` (or parent `^model`), you can use [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

```
app.directive('tag', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        require: "ngModel",
        templateUrl: '../../Content/templates/RecruitingGroups/Tag.html',
        link: function ( scope, el, attrs, ngModelCtrl ) {
            scope.doSomething = function() {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue( 'testing' ); // Update model
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm I tried the first approach but it broke throwing this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'TagIds' of undefined.

Comment: I somewhat got it. I just through out binding to displaytags and just let it bind to TagIds. That pretty much gave me what I want anyhow.